# Referencing Webpage using "apalike" and "natbib

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I need to reference some websites in my paper using APA style, I am using natbib and apalike in my tex file.

Here is my bibtex record

```
@misc{cnn2011rahm,
    Author = {Editor CNN},
    Date-Added = {2013-11-21 09:15:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-11-21 09:26:00 +0000},
    Howpublished = {http://edition.cnn.com/2011/POLITICS/01/27/emanuel.ballot/},
    Lastchecked = {Nov 01, 2013},
    Month = {January},
    Title = {Illinois Supreme Court keeps Emanuel on ballot},
    Url = {http://edition.cnn.com/2011/POLITICS/01/27/emanuel.ballot/},
    Urldate = {Jan 28, 2011},
    Year = {2011}}
```

But when it was render, it is showed this way

[image]

And the necessary information e.g. last accessed is not shown, may I know how do I fix this?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use another author-year bibliography style that deals with urls such as the Journal of Statistical Software `jss2` style available [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic?lang=en).

Comment: For more details of the above discussions one may refer to the following site [http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-citeURL.html](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-citeURL.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `apalike` bibliography style has been around more or less unchanged since 1988. Back then, web pages didn't exist yet -- at least not as items that might be cited in bibliographies. The entry type `@misc` thus doesn't recognize, and hence blissfully ignores, fields named `url`, `urldate`, and `lastchecked`.

A workaround involves these steps:

- rename the field `Lastchecked` to `note`,
- modify the contents of the `note` field from `Nov 01, 2013` to `Last accessed on Nov 01, 2013`, and (optionally)
- encase the URL string in the `howpublished` field in a `\url{...}` wrapper.

Separately, you should also encase the contents of the `author` and `title` fields in pairs of curly braces. This prevents BibTeX from (a) misinterpreting the author as a person with first name `Editor` and last name `CNN` and (b) lowercasing the words `Supreme`, `Court`, and `Emanuel` in the `title` field.

Aside: If you need to cite a lot of web pages, you may be better off in the long run choosing a bibliography style which does know what to do with fields named `url`, `urldate`, and `lastchecked`.

Here's an MWE that implements these ideas. Note the changes I applied to the following fields: `author`, `title`, `howpublished`, and `urldate` (renamed to `note`).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{rahm.bib}
@misc{cnn2011rahm,
    Author = {{Editor CNN}},
    Date-Added = {2013-11-21 09:15:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-11-21 09:26:00 +0000},
    Howpublished = {\url{http://edition.cnn.com/2011/POLITICS/01/27/emanuel.ballot/}},
    note = {Last checked on Nov~01, 2013},
    Month = {January},
    Title = {Illinois {Supreme Court} keeps {Emanuel} on ballot},
    Url = {http://edition.cnn.com/2011/POLITICS/01/27/emanuel.ballot/},
    Urldate = {Jan 28, 2011},
    Year = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{cnn2011rahm} reports that \dots
\bibliography{rahm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which citation style includes webpages?

Comment: @Stophface - There are lots and lots of bibliography styles out there that are set up to recognize and process fields such as `url` and `doi`. If you're looking for a suitable list, you should post a *new* query. It would be helpful if you provided some information as to which formatting requirements you have to (or would like to) satisfy.

Comment: Well explained.