# Updated apalike or unsrt that handles websites?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

This may be considered a duplicate of [Referencing Webpage using "apalike" and "natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146158/referencing-webpage-using-apalike-and-natbib).

I am not using natbib, I want

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

or

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

But as noted, they don't handle citations of website.

I find the 'apalike bibliography style has been more or less unchanged since 1988' response bizarre, and that the advised solution(s) are normally to hack your .bib file and trick other types into conforming with apalike.

**Question - Is someone able to point me to an apalike2017.bst file that is essentially the default apalike + instructions for formatting websites?**

I'm not confident enough to try and make that myself.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the `apacite` package and the `apacite` bibliography style (can be used with or without `natbib`, although it's not clear why you *don't* want to use `natbib`.)  And the reason why old styles don't get updated is because other better and more conforming styles show up (like `apacite` or `biblatex-apa`).  See [Perfect APA style bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191404/2693).

Comment: Also [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812/2693).  Either of these are effectively duplicates for the APA part of your question. For `unsrt` you should ask a separate question since they are very different styles, although the answer will also be to use `natbib` or `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @AlanMunn I see your valuable input into lots of latex questions! I didn't want to use natbib because I think it was breaking the package bibentry (which I'm using but could probably avoid if need be). I really wanted to avoid hacking my .bib file, currently it is being generated by the Papers app, but I think I'm going to have to manually edit it for the websites (which it calls a 'webpage'.

Comment: I'll keep trying some of these options. The frustrating part is both apalike and unsrt compile fine, everything else I'm trying has various issues. It's a 50k+ word thesis with lots of 'include' etc so a MWE is tricky.